# Python win32com workbook.SaveAs 'Invalid number of parameters.' error

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have been running a python script successfully for several months.  The script edits a template excel spreadsheet using the `win32com` commands and then saves the edited workbook as a new .xlsx file.

```
results_path = "C:\\Users\\...\\"   
results_title = results_path + input + "_Results.xlsx"

if os.path.exists(template_path):
    xl= win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename= template_path)
    xl.Application.Cells(2,6).Value = input
    r = 17
    for row in y_test:
        row = str(row)
        row = row[1:]
        row = row[:-1]
        xl.Application.Cells(r,2).Value = row
        r += 1
#           xl.Application.CalculateFullRebuild
#           xl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename = save_title)
#           time.sleep(20)
    r = 17
    for row in prediction:
        row = str(row)
        row = row[1:]
        row = row[:-1]
        xl.Application.Cells(r,3).Value = row
        r += 1
    xl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename = results_title)
```

Without changing anything in the script it no longer works.  One day it just stopped working

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-5-aaef40198ed6>", line 1, in <module>
runfile('C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Stocks/Python Stock Code/BizNet.py', wdir='C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Stocks/Python Stock Code')

File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 710, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

File "C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/Stocks/Python Stock Code/BizNet.py", line 99, in <module>
BizNet_test.accuracy_Test(companyInputOrderArray,input,model)

File "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Stocks\Python Stock Code\BizNet_test.py", line 125, in accuracy_Test
xl.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(results_title)

File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.5\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\_Workbook.py", line 284, in SaveAs
, AccessMode, ConflictResolution, AddToMru, TextCodepage, TextVisualLayout

com_error: (-2147352562, 'Invalid number of parameters.', None, None)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46496182/edit) to include more information.  Since it's a COM error, I wonder if perhaps a Windows component was updated and win32com is looking for an old version.  Did you recently change Excel versions?

Answer (score 3):

Got it!!!

There was a temporary cache folder "gen_py" that I had to delete. The one that was referenced by the file path in the error.

```
"C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\gen_py\3.5\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x9\_Workbook.py"
```

I have no clue why this worked or how the error initially occurred, but everything is fine now.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution resolved the issue.